# Convert String to <S3Uri>

Tags: string, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am working on a PowerShell script, which calls AWS CLI commands. I am using the below Sync command, however the command expects the bucket name as `<S3Uri>`. The script will get the bucket in the form of String. Can anyone please tell me how to convert String type to `<S3Uri>` type. It has to be either a Powershell cmdlet or AWS CLI command.

Command:

```
aws --endpoint-url $endpoint s3 sync $InputPath $BucketName --profile test
```

Answer (score 7):

An `S3Uri` simply looks like:

```
s3://bucket-name/path/object.txt
```

By the way, it is rare that you will need to use `--endpoint-url`. You should typically use `--region`. It is mostly used when pointing to an *S3-compatible* service, such as a local Snowball device.